# javascript `localeCompare` return different values

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting, native

I am now working in `javascript` `string` sorting using `localeCompare` and my data will contain several `null` values too.

And i found a weird behavior with `localeCompare` when comparing `string` and `null` value. When comparing string value upto startswith `a/A to n/N` it working fine as below.

```
"n".localeCompare(null) // return -1;
"N".localeCompare(null) // return -1;
```

But after if i compare the null value with `o/O to z/Z` it returns `1`

```
"o".localeCompare(null) // return 1;
"O".localeCompare(null) // return 1;
```

I know that `localeCompare` work with comparing `Unicode` but why the above behavior happens is there any reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`localeCompare` compares strings, as such anything passed to it will be converted to a string, and you'll get the same result from

```
"n".localeCompare("null") // return -1;
"o".localeCompare("null") // return 1;
```

because

> The localeCompare() method returns a **number indicating whether a**
>   **reference string comes before or after** or is the same as the given
>   string in sort order.

[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

which means

`"null".localeCompare("null")` -> will return `0` as it's the same string
`"n".localeCompare("null")` -> will return `-1` as it comes before `null`
`"o".localeCompare("null")` -> will return `1` as it comes after `null`

Comment: Thanks for you reply. You mean the `null` is converted into string when passed as argument to the `localeCompare` and so should i handle it outside??

Comment: `localeCompare` **only** compares strings, so yes anything passed to it will be treated as a string, and null isn't a string and can't really be compared to `n`. How you handle that, depends on what you're expecting when comparing strings and `null` ?

Comment: Thanks it explains lot, i am going to mark this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

## If you want a real-world comparer that can handle `null` values

Then, you are better off implementing something like this,

```
function stringComparer(a,b) {
  if(a && b)
    return a.localeCompare(b);
  else 
    // sort null and "" to bottom
    if(a)
      return -1;
    else if(b)
      return 1;
    else 
      return 0;
}
```

and using it to compare your values. Here is an example,

```
['Łove','Love',null,"",null,'kellogs','Kellogs','kellogs',null,"Lover","   ",'Man',"abc", "AAb", "Abc"].sort(stringComparer)
```

There is some room for improving this depending on how you want null, "   " and "" values to sort in relation to each other. In the above implementation, "  " will sort to the top while null and "" values will sort to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare):

> "All values are coerced to strings, so omitting it or passing undefined causes localeCompare() to compare against the string "undefined", which is rarely what you want."

So it's literally comparing the string `"null"`.

You unfortunately need to check for undefined values and handle them.
And you can't just check for 1 or -1 because:

> Warning: Do not rely on exact return values of -1 or 1!
> Negative and positive integer results vary between browsers (as well as between browser versions) because the ECMAScript specification only mandates negative and positive values. Some browsers may return -2 or 2, or even some other negative or positive value.

You will want to grab the value live to confirm. For example:

```js
let basicCompare = "a".localeCompare("b");
```

Then code to compare two strings A and B:

```js
if (!A && B) {
  return -(basicCompare);
}
```

You would need another condition for `if A && !B`, an initial one if both `A && B` exist. And a final fourth for if both don't exist.